# Adding LC filter to PNP circuit

Tags: oscillator, pnp, passive-filter

Let's say I want to add a L1C1 filter to power supply of PNP oscillator to avoid a current spikes drained from battery.
In case of NPN circuits the designers usually place the L1 to Vcc rail.
However, I think in PNP circuits the L1 should be placed into Gnd rail.
The reason is to keep emitter on stable rail.

Am I correct?
Also, where to put the L4 used for limiting the Led current?
I decided connect L4 to most floated leg to keep one side of Led stable.

*(Note: The biasing resistor R1 is connected directly to Gnd to ensure a constant bias, otherwise would be floated as C1 voltage swings)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgefS9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(L2L3 are coupled)

Comment: Why don't you simulate your circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka I measured a real sample. I wrote in question what I found out and what I think about it. The oscillator drains 2A(2us) every 100us so for battery protection I must added L1C1 filter. Bottom of C1 flyes from the batt. perspective, the top is stable so the emitter is on stable point. So this solution should be more sufficient then putting L1 to Vcc.

Comment: If you used a simulator you would see that the filter can be in either rail.